# Conditional render based on route

Tags: reactjs, dom, conditional-statements, render, router

I have an element that I want to display only when I'm on "/" route if It's changing I want to hide the element
how should I do it correctly?
I'm using react-router-dom, to change the route I use   so I guess that's the problem, what am I missing?, also I tried to use if (history.location == '/') then/else
its doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `<Route />` component from `react-router-dom`.

From the [official react-router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route):

> The Route component is perhaps the most important component in React Router to understand and learn to use well. Its most basic responsibility is to render some UI when its path matches the current URL.

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => (
  <h1>My Home Component</h1>
);

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Route exact path="/">
      <Home />
    </Route>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-albattani-b0y03?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Do not forget to add exact props in **<Route path="/" exact />** to avoid to be loaded when you have a route like **"/myroute/"**

Comment: I guess i wasn't correct well while explaining my problem
actually I need to hide an element only on route '/' and then show it at any another route, if you have an idea I would like to try it, thanks